# How to have Git ignore merge conflicts where the file was deleted in the destination branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I don't know if this is possible, but it sure would be sweet.

Let's say I have two branches: `master` and `releases`.

The `master` branch has all of these files:

- index.html
- style.scss
- style.css

In the `releases` branch, I've deleted the `scss` file, because there's no point in my including that development file in the release. That means that in the `releases` branch I have these files:

- index.html
- style.css

But let's say that I work on the files in the master branch. I edit the `scss` file, it compiles into `css`, and I'm ready for a new release.

**I want to be able to easily merge `master` into `releases`.** Of course, the merging isn't the trouble. It easily merges the changes in `index.html` and `style.css` into the corresponding files in the `releases` branch.

But when it gets to `style.scss` there is a merge conflict (obviously) because `style.scss` doesn't exist in the `releases` branch--which is of course because I don't want it in the `releases` branch.

So, I can manually choose to prefer the destination branch's version of the situation: no `style.scss` file. I guess doing it manually is okay...

**But what about when I have many files that I've deleted in the releases branch and don't ever want to bring in to the releases branch?** Every time I merge I can go through and for each and every file resolve the conflict. But it would be way sweeter if there was a way that I could somehow say: "merge all the changes from `master`, but if you run in to a situation where the destination file does not exist, ignore merging that file."

Possible?

Comment: I suggest making a completely separate branch (or repo) for those "non-releasable" files.  Or, write a script which copies only files on a manifest from the release branch to an actual release tarball etc.

Comment: Do you mean that when merging `master` and `release`, you want git to totally ignore some of the files in master branch ?

Comment: @NomanUrRehman, yes, that's it.

Comment: I am not sure git allows to do something like this by default but git is open to plugin development plus it has a hooks feature that you can look into. I think this needs to be done programmatically where some files do not move from one branch to another.

Comment: normally you would separate the production and supportive files directory-wise, so that your `index.html` and `style.css` would sit in published directory, and `style.scss` somewhere else, so no git magic would be needed.

Comment: @MykolaGurov, my actual files are separated by directory (`/scss`, `/css`, etc.), I just simplified the above example for communication purposes. I don't see how separating them helps, though? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I would expect that after proper separation you don't have to delete the files in the `releases` branch.

Comment: Hmm, I think one of us doesn't understand; it may be me. Here's the deal. My Git repository includes all my development files (because I need them during development :), but I don't want them in the `releases` branch. My dilemma is that I want them in one branch but not the other. But I want all other changes that happen in the `master` branch to be merged to the `releases` branch--except for changes in the development files. This causes a merge-conflict, because edited dev files don't exist in the releases branch.